# Extending Navbar with Page Resizing Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

When I first installed twitter bootstrap and hadn't edited any Bootstrap code (the carousel) the navbar looked normal but it was a bit away from the edge.

And this is what it looked like when it was resized small:
[image]

Then when I changed the size of the navbar so it fit the entire page using CSS height and width it started glitching out:

When the browser wasn't resized it looked normal but if you made the browser smaller:

[image]

Also if the browser wasn't at the default size but it wasn't really small it would move away from the edge.

This is the code to make the collapsing function:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

This is the CSS code for my navbar:

```
.navbar{position:relative;top:65px;height:75px;width: 100%;margin-bottom:20px;border:1px solid transparent}
```

How can I keep the collapsing thing and also make sure the navbar is always going from the edge to edge of the web page without it glitching out and the words disappearing and stuff like that?

Comment: When you're working with responsive, don't make static width like width:50px, instead make width go with percentage values like width: 100%.
Also you can play with max-width or min-width for more control..

Comment: you need to include your CSS, right now it's a mystery, we can't read code from your images

Comment: @AbuOmar I changed it to width: 100% but it won't fill up all the way. It did fix the text glitching out and it also made the collapse function work but it's not going from edge to edge.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice your HTML was incomplete as well and only has the button part. Please add the whole HTML or at least the navbar, it looks like you have some unclosed div

Comment: @Devin I got this solved. In future questions I'll try and remember to add all my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use bootstrap you'll only need to remove "container" class from the parents of "navbar" in your html, that'll make the navbar goes full width